# How to include Fonts package and CSS frameworks in Angular Story Book?

Tags: angular, storybook

Where do we include any external fonts in  Angular storybook ?
I'm using materialize css and some google fonts.
HTML :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS: 
Within angular-cli.json I have this

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
  ]
```

Answer (score 20):

About the link tags for loading Google fonts, [Custom Head Tags](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/add-custom-head-tags/) is designed for such situation:

Add a file named `preview-head.html` under `.storybook` directory (by default), where is the html tags that you want to insert:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

To load styles listed in `angular.json` file (`angular-cli.json` has been replaced since Angular 6 +), make sure that you have installed the `@storybook/angular` version 5+, which has provided a default webpack configuration internally that would read configuration from `angular.json` configuration. See the official example: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/examples/angular-cli/package.json

I've been using the features above with Angular 8 and they work at the version of 5.3

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by me as a hack, import `loadGlobalStyles` function to storybook's config:

```
const links = [
  {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons',
  },
  {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400',
  },
];

// to prevent duplication with HMR
function isLinkExist(option) {
  return !!document.querySelector(`link[href='${option.href}']`);
}

function insertLink(options) {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  Object.assign(link, options);

  document.head.insertBefore(link, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

export function loadGlobalStyles() {
  links.forEach(link => isLinkExist(link) ? null : insertLink(link));
}
```